# Math.max or sum within array.reduce which is better in terms of performance

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

we have been solving a problem to check whether array have any item with >0 value but someone now there is 2 approaches using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

a. using Math.max ( which is wrong at first place but let it be)

b. using simple reduce method with initial value 0;

I am not sure how to check with jsperf.com so created below snippet with `console.time()` and checked in chrome console, but problem is that each time result is changed in such a way that sometimes *a* took less time than *b* whereas sometimes *b* took less time than *a*

result vary on each run block.

please guide me with proof which is better

here is my snippet to test

```
{
 const input = [0,10,20,30,8,0,0];
 const sumOutput = () => input.reduce( (c, a) => c +=a , 0);
 const maxOutput = () => input.reduce( (a,b) => Math.max(a,b));

 console.time('sum');
 input.forEach( () => sumOutput() );
 console.timeEnd('sum');

 console.log(' ======' );

 console.time('max');
 input.forEach( () => maxOutput() );
 console.timeEnd('max');

 }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the purpose of this. both code serve different purpose, why do you need to compare each other.

Comment: side node, to get max value in array, can use `Math.max(...input)` instead of `reduce()`

Comment: No, we are not getting max value.  we need to check whether each element of an array is 0 or not? someone use Math.max() which seems completely invalid to me

Comment: @Dean exactly but fellow developer uses Math.max() which was wrong at first place as our problem was to check whether array have value greater than 0

Comment: ok understand, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is really confusing. You are benchmarking `Math.max` vs `+` (seems odd btw, since it does not achieve the same thing), why would you introduce `Array.reduce` in the problem (seems totally irrelevant) ==> downvote

Comment: My question was not to solve some issue but to get performance of these 2 methods appraches

Comment: But if you use reduce for finding the max you can simply do `input.reduce((s, e) => s = s < e? e: s)` which is really snappy and beats your max function as well as Math.max(array)... at least in Firefox Quantum.

Comment: the performance will necessarily be javascript-engine dependent thus browser (or other) dependent. If you want to compare performance, you have to clearly define the environment, you cannot simply claim some function of the language is "faster" than another, be careful about assuming this because of some tests you did in your specific situation. The language defines semantics and behaviour, not performance (maybe it defines some complexity of algorithm, but in no way this is an absolute time comparison)

Comment: And also, as other have stated, what you are comparing is not really clear. I don't understand what you will get from that. "Well, since `Max` is faster than doing a sum, let's replace all of ours sums by using `Max`" ? I hope you agree it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time varies because JavaScript is a little wonky in how it runs. If the garbage collector fires during your code or the millisecond time didn't start at exactly 0 your result is going to be off.

The simplest solution is to scale your tests with a loop, since that reduces the impact of timing inaccuracies:

```js
var tests = 1000000;
var input = [0, 10, 20, 30, 8, 0, 0];
var sumOutput = function() {
  return input.reduce(function(c, a) {
    return c += a;
  }, 0);
};
var maxOutput = function() {
  return input.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  });
};
console.time('sum');
var i = tests;
while (i--) {
  input.forEach(function() {
    return sumOutput();
  });
}
console.timeEnd('sum');
console.log(' ======');
console.time('max');
var i = tests;
while (i--) {
  input.forEach(function() {
    return maxOutput();
  });
}
console.timeEnd('max');
```

Comment: so max took less time than sum!!! why we are using Math library than it must took more time than simple summation

Comment: thanks for the quick tip but I am using es6 concepts. IMO using `var` and `const` must impact difference as well as using `=>` instead of `function()`

Comment: @pro.mean Mostly to support legacy browsers. array.reduce didn't work until IE9 but the Math library has always been available. Besides being older, Math.max also handles differently in that it always returns numbers (even if that number is NaN).

Comment: my issue is not about the support but to check the performance. I am using chrome only.

Comment: This guy got very opposing results:
https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/9760/0/mathmax-vs-arrayreduce
I think the values also should not be the same, but random values to test properly.